# 2.80 install wiped out 2.79

Tags: installation

I just installed Blender 2.80. Went well, new version looks good. BUT... it wiped out my existing 2.79 exe and won't let me reinstall 2.79.  I need 2.79 to do scenery development for Xplane 11.  What must I do to get back to Blender 2.79?  Would be nice to have both 2.79 and 2.80 installed, but MUST have 2.79!
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the archive version of 2.79b for your platform, which doesn't require installation.

- [Windows 64-bit](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows64.zip)
- [Windows 32-bit](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows32.zip)
- [Linux 64-bit](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2)
- [Linux 32-bit](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-i686.tar.bz2)
- [macOS](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-macOS-10.6.zip)

Once extracted you should be able to run Blender 2.79b normally. Unlike the installer the archive doesn't give you a start menu entry or shortcut. You will need to create that shortcut yourself or start it directly from the directory the binary is in.

Comment: Thank you, rjg, that worked! Now to get back to work.

Comment: @JamesC. You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark next to it, if this answer solved your problem.